# Посимвольный вывод слов

Tags: php, utf-8, unicode

Здравствуйте!

Есть такая конструкция, которая выведет первую букву переменной `$str`, которая будет равна `'t'`:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$str = 'test';
print_r($str[0]);   //    выведет 't'
```

Но почему это не работает с русскими словами?

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$str = 'тест';
print_r($str[0]);   //    выведет '�', вместо 'т'
```

Кодировка вроде выставлена, но почему в выводе  знак вопроса?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить?

Спасибо!

Comment: значит квадратные скобки работают в байтах а не в символах и собственно возвращают первый байт строки. А русские буквы в utf-8 занимают 2 байта

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php используйте.

Comment: @Visman, Спасибо! Я решил через preg_split, просто стало интересно почему возникает эта проблема.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё дело в том, что в кодировке UTF-8 единичный символ может занимать разное количество байт (от 1 до 6 или даже больше).

Английские буквы, цифры, некоторые знаки препинания занимают по одному байту, и их представление ничем не отличается, как если бы они были закодированы в ASCII. Для букв русского алфавита, букв европейских языков, которых нет английском (например, немецкая Ö), для арабского алфавита, нужно уже по два байта. Распространённые восточные иероглифы занимают уже по 3 байта каждый. А всеми любимые эмодзи кодируются последовательностями от 4 байтов.

Итак, давайте рассмотрим байтовое представление ваших строк.

- `test` -> `74 65 73 74`
- `тест` -> `D1 82 D0 B5 D1 81 D1 82`

Слева показано то, как эти буквы видим мы, справа — их побайтовое представление в памяти компьютера, причём значения байтов записаны в 16-ричной системе счисления (чтобы не занять много места). Как видите, русское слово занимает в два раза больше памяти, хотя букв в нём столько же. Кроме того, обратите внимание, каждый байт в его кодированном варианте не меньше 80<sub>16</sub>.

Теперь вернёмся к PHP. Строки в этом языке о кодировках ничего не знают, а просто хранят в себе только байты. И оператор индексирования тоже ничего про кодировки, буквы, символы не знает; он просто, будучи применённым к строке, возвращает байт с указанным номером. Поэтому, когда вы пытаетесь напечатать первый байт (с номером 0), в первом случае выводится байт со значением 74<sub>16</sub>, который на экране компьютера виден как маленькая латинская буква «t». А во втором случае на вывод подаётся байт со значением D1<sub>16</sub>, представляющий собой огрызок русской буквы «т»; не зная, какой байт идёт дальше, устройство вывода (терминал или веб-обозреватель) просто рисует знак вопроса.

Что же делать, как напечатать только первый символ из строки? В качестве решения можно применить функции из расширения **php-mbstring**.

```
$letter = mb_substr($str, 0, 1);  // вернёт первый code point из строки
```

Но учтите, функция [mb_substr](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php) оперирует понятием code point, а не graphical cluster. Какое же это имеет значение? Стандарт юникода позволяет составлять некоторые буквы из нескольких code points. К примеру, буква «ё» может оказаться комбинацией буквы «е» и умляута.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `mb_substr`:

```
mb_substr($string, $letter, 1, "utf-8");
//$string - строка
//$letter - индекс нужной буквы
//1 - сколько символов включая нужную нужно вернуть
//"utf-8" - кодировка
```